# Flutter: Is there a way to display multi bulleted list?

Tags: flutter, indentation, bulletedlist

How do you display a list like this in flutter?

[image]

Like for numbers no indentions, for "*" 1 indention, "o" 2 indentions and so on.

Comment: Do you have the same model for item 1, 2,3....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such mechanic built into Flutter. I'm not sure how many lists you want to display, how long the lists can be and where the data is coming from.

[flutter_markdown](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown) is a good solution if you also need paragraphs and other text styles. Just supply your list in [markdown format](https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown-quick-reference/) to the widget.

You can also build an indented list with Flutter core widgets:

- Use a `Column` or `ListView` for the list of items
- Use `Row`s to position the widgets of a single list item
- Use a `Text` or `Icon` widget to display bullets or numbers
- Use a `Text` widget to display the item text (wrapped by `Expanded` widget)
- Use `SizedBox(width: ...)` to add margins, paddings and indentation

Comment: Thank you boformer! I'll try all of your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Hi boformer! This is what I've been looking for. Just an additional, is there any way to change the "bullet" character in every level of the list because in all level it's just using the same "bullet" character? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you went with markdown. Take a look at the source code of the library.

Comment: Hello boformer. Yup. I used markdown. Okay. I'll take a look at the source code. Thank you very much!